# C# Calling a URL: Timeout

Tags: c#, url, .net-4.0, httpwebrequest, process.start

I am trying to write a part of a program that notifies the Admin that a clients data has been updated/sent by calling a URL that sends an email to the admin.  I have been successful in doing this but only on Windows 7 and 2003.  I need it to run on Windows server 2008.  It also needs to this by hiding the web browser from the user when the url is called.  I have been successful in sending the email if I let the explorer window open but if I try and hide the window it always fails.
The code I am using is as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url += strNewValue);
// execute the request
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();

Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    response.Close();

/*   
    WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
        web.AllowNavigation = true;
        web.Visible = false;
        web.Navigate(url+strNewValue);
*/
/*
    ProcessStartInfo startweb = new ProcessStartInfo(url + strNewValue);
        startweb.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        startweb.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startweb.UseShellExecute = true;
        startweb.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process.Start(startweb);
*/
```

The commented code is showing the other attempts that I have tried to make this work.  This code all seem to work successfully on Windows 2007 and Windows Server 2003 but I cannot get it to work on Windows 2008 Server which is a must.

Every time it gets to this section of the code in the application, the program starts to NOT RESPOND, eventually recovers and says that it has sent the notification.  However, it freezes at this point in the application and the email is never sent.  I have checked this URL and it sends the email without any issues when done manually.  I am currently using the .NET 4.0 Client package if this is potentially causing any issues.  the only error that I get is a timeout error with httpwebresponse getresponse();

Any advice would be extremely helpful.  Thank you in advance

Comment: It sounds like to me that your Windows Server 2008 machine is behind a restrictive firewall that does not allow the connection. Nothing you can do about that from code, you will need to get your network administrator to allow the connection.

Comment: also, it looks like there be some limited support for the ProcessStartInfo class on Server 2008. i'd check the doc page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) to see if those restrictions apply here, too.

Comment: Can you load the URL in the browser on the machine?

Comment: I checked the firewall. The firewall is off.  And yes I can load the URL in the browser on the machine.

Comment: Can you load the URL + whatever query string in a browser on the machine?

Comment: Is it your proxy configuration? You might have to set the `Proxy` property on your request: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx

Comment: Yes the url+query string can be loaded on the browser on the machine as well

Answer (score 0):

Can you instead configure the objects from the `System.Net.Mail` namespace such as `SmtpClient` and send the e-mail directly yourself? This solution introduces a seemingly unnecessary and complex/prone to failure process into sending an e-mail, which is a fairly trivial task to do programmatically.

[SmtpClient MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

Comment: No I cant use the SmtpClient because the API call isnt always for email.  I just used email for testing purposes to get an immediate result.